# You requested too many nodes (limit is 50000). Either request a smaller area, or use planet.osm

Tags: openstreetmap

I'm using http://www.openstreetmap.org/ export utility to generate
a .osm (xml map file) of an area, to later generate a .map file with
osmosis, but i can't extract the .osm because i got this error:

"You requested too many nodes (limit is 50000). Either request a
smaller area, or use planet.osm"

How can i generate maps of more than 50.000 nodes? how to use
planet.osm? i'm blocked :S

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the message says, if you need to process large amount of data, you generally have two options:

1. Generate smaller requests, and later merge them before processing (this is probably not an ideal method, generally).
2. Download [planet.osm](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm), which is a database dump of the *whole* of OpenStreetMap, and process it. Since it is a huge file (several GB), the first step when processing this file is usually to extract the part which is interesting for you, and there are already preprocessed extracts available (e.g. [on Geofabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/osm/)).

Comment: yes, i have spain.osm.pbf, and i want the area of barcelona city, but i have NO IDEA of how to generate barcelona.osm........ i'm in the same point as the begining

Comment: So, you do have all the data you need downloaded, you just want to extract a smaller portion from it? If you know the bounding box of the interesting area, I would say pbftoosm (https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Pbftoosm) should be the easiest way to go.

Comment: ok, i have a 22mb osm file now, but, now, how can i transform this OSM into a binary .map file to use it with mapsforge? i have to do it with osmosis, but i dont know the way

Answer (score 6):

My favourite way is to use the [Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API). Here's how:

Put something like this into the query form at http://www.overpass-api.de/query_form.html, changing the four bounding edges s, n, w, and e to the southern, northern, western and eastern edges of your desired data. (Use the [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) export tab to drag out a rectangle and get the bounds.)

```
<osm-script timeout="10000" element-limit="1073741824">
  <union into="_">
    <bbox-query into="_" s="52" n="52.4" w="4.8" e="5"/>
    <recurse from="_" into="_" type="up"/>
    <recurse from="_" into="_" type="down"/>
  </union>
  <print from="_" limit="" order="id"/>
</osm-script>
```

I got this method straight from a good authority: one of the Overpass developers. I have used it successfully. One proviso: it recurses twice, to get all the ways that are members of relations overlapping the rectangle, then to get all the points in those ways.

The script sets the timeout to 10,000 seconds and the element limit to a suitably large number.

Answer (score 1):

There are [several ways to download raw map data from OpenStreetMap](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data) ranging from small bite-sized chunks via the API (you need larger areas) through to downloading the whole planet (more data than you need).

In the middleground there's options to download pre-prepared files for [countries](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Country_and_area_extracts) or [cities](http://metro.teczno.com) (that's more like it). Or as graham asher points out, the OverpassAPI is a flexible a API which works for largish areas.

I have a tool "[XAPI Query Builder](http://harrywood.co.uk/maps/uixapi/xapi.html)", which makes it easy to figure out an old style XAPI/OverpassAPI URL (bit outdated these days) or alternatively an Osmosis command.

Once you have got the desired area of data as file such as bremen.osm ...

[From the MapsForge documentation](http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/wiki/GettingStartedMapWriter#Basic_Options) :

"

Write map file for Bremen using XML format and writing into file /tmp/bremen.map, setting map start position to Bremen HBF:

```
$ bin/osmosis --rx file=../data/bremen.osm --mapfile-writer file=/tmp/bremen.map map-start-position=53.083418,8.81376
```

"

Seems fairly clear, but maybe you're getting stuck earlier. Did you [install osmosis](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Installation) and [set it up with the map-writer plugin](http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/wiki/GettingStartedMapWriter#Plugin_Installation)?